# Flash doesnt show up until mouse over on ie. How to fix that?

Tags: html, apache-flex, flash

I developed something in flex. It works great on FF and Safari. But on IE the "swf area" remains blank until mouse moves over it. I am embedding it like that:

```
<object height="100%" width="100%" id="myApp">
<param value="example.swf" name="movie"/>
<param value="high" name="quality"/>
<param value="opaque" name="wmode"/>
<param value="always" name="allowScriptAccess"/>
<param value="true" name="allowFullScreen"/>
<embed height="100%" width="100%" wmode="opaque" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" name="myApp" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" quality="high" src="example.swf"/>
</object>
```

What can I do? I dont want to use javascript for it, because I need to easily copy/paste my "embedding code" on other webpages. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here: http://f-source.com/flash/fix/
 It's not a bug it's a feature

Comment: Thank you. I saw also another js solution here: http://forums.adobe.com/message/1995276

What I can not get is why most flash doesnt need such thing to run on ie, and some (such as mine) do? Isnt there pure html (or flash/flex) fix? I dont want to use js :/

Comment: I'd suggest to have a look at the source code of such a site. Maybe it depends on your version of IE?

Comment: I think there is no alternative.. so i am using js :/

Comment: I don't think this is the same as the "click to activate" feature. That shows the flash object and just doesn't activate it until its clicked. The blank area until "hovered" not clicked I believe to be an entirely different issue, which I get all the time as well but only with swf's that I made in Flex but I don't have this issue with apps I made with flash (non flex).

Answer (score 1):

If you call focus on the swf object after the page loads like so:

```
document.getElementById('SWFObject').focus();
```

It should fix this problem. However this isn't a perfect solution because I am currently having an issue with a page where I have 2 Flex apps embedded on it, and calling focus on both isn't fixing the issue.